# How can I pass datasets between %pyspark interpreter and %python interpreters in Zeppelin?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm writing a code where I'm fetching a dataset using an internal library and %pyspark interpreter. *However I am unable to pass the dataset to %python interpreter.* I tried using string variables and it is working fine, but with dataset I'm using the following code to put dataset in a zeppelin context- `z.put("input_data",input_data)`

and it is throwing the following error:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'`.

Can you please tell me how can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to share your variable between pyspark and python interpreter or between two pyspark interpreters?

Comment: It works fine while sharing between same interpreters. Right now I want to share it between pyspark and python

Comment: Any reason why you want to share between pyspark & python ? because pyspark could do whatever python can do

Comment: @zjffdu We were using a company internal API which is only supported by Python.

Comment: As I said above, pyspark should unable to whatever python can do. So I could not understand why you can not use pyspark directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the result in ResourcePool via print it to %table.

```
%python
print('%table a\tb\n408+\t+408\n0001\t++99\n40817810300001453030\t0000040817810300001453030')
```

Then get in such way.

```
%spark.pyspark
ic = z.getInterpreterContext()
pool = ic.getResourcePool()
paragraphId = "20180828-093109_1491500809"
t = pool.get(ic.getNoteId(), paragraphId, "zeppelin.paragraph.result.table").get().toString()

print(t)
```

This way allows to transfer up to 50-100 megabytes of raw data.

Anyway I recommend to follow @zjffdu to use only one of these interpreters.