# How to merge clickhouse and postgresql query?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am using Apache zeppelin,I can get results from both postgres and clickhouse seperately. But I need to merge both queries.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have two jdbc interpreters: PostgreSQL and ClickHouse.

You can get query result as string in %python or %spark.pyspark interpreters [in such way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52051588/4545870). Then convert strings to Pandas DataFrames and merge.

Also you can download data from ClickHouse to python, convert to Pandas DataFrame and upload to PostgreSQL by [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). In this way you must have rights to write in PostgreSQL.