# using Dataframe from %pyspark to %python in zeppelin

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I have a pandas dataframe in %pyspark, I want to use it in %python cell in zeppelin. I am unable to do it. Any idea how that can be done?

Comment: You can't do it directly without storing the data somewhere external to the two instances (csv, pickle...).

Comment: Please check early answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/52051588/4545870

Answer (score 0):

you can use it directly, after all, it is all python, %pyspark is just a python's API to use spark with the python language, also you can switch between pandas DataFrames and pyspark DataFrame:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('app_name').getOrCreate()
your_pyspark_df = spark.createDataFrame(your_pd_df)
```

also, you can return to pandas DataFrame with the .toPandas() method.